# Nginx location trouble

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

So I am trying to create location direction where only / would be moved to subfolder /fr but I am failing and can't find the reason. This is nginx docker container exposed on k8s. It's bi lingual app, /fr is default language. Locations  /fr and /en exist, rest don't so idea is that all non existing locations are moved to /fr , root doesn't contain index.html so it should be moved to /fr too and /en stays there. Here is the code:

```
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ fr/index.html;
    }

    location = / {
        return 301 $scheme://$server_name/fr/index.html;
    }

    location /de {
        try_files $uri $uri/ fr/index.html;
    }

    location /en {
        try_files $uri $uri/ en/index.html;
```

Everything works except `= /` . Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Well everything is working, it's stupid Chrome that caches old responses even though I was testing from incognito mode...